# Como fazer a atualização de um tabela por ID?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma tabela e nela tenho um *icon* com o evento `onClick`, o *script* até então está fazendo seu trabalho que é mudar o estado de `true` para `false`, caso esse seja clicado.

Meu trabalho está sendo em atualizar essa tabela sempre que isso ocorre?

```js
function Change(val){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{idsocial :val},
        url: "change_01.php",
        success: function(){

       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Atualizar o que exatamente? Não entendi.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi, no arquivo `change_01.php`, você terá que fazer um `UPDATE` no banco, utilizando as informações de id e valor enviadas pelo ajax...

Comment: Acho que a "tabela" a qual se refere seja uma tabela HTML...
A questão está ambígua, falta informações básicas do que está fazendo e o que ou como pretende fazer.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @user8828 Edite a pergunta deixando mais claro oque tu realmente quer. Principalmente informe se a tabela a que tu se refere é uma tabela HTML ou tabela do banco de dados do servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que no seu arquivo `change_01.php` fazer a alteração do banco de dados através de um comando `SQL` de update

```
mysql_query("UPDATE sua_tabela SET campo_atualizado = ".$_POST["estado_campo"]." WHERE idsocial = ".$_POST["idsocial"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu assumi que oque tu sua dificuldade é atualizar a tabela HTML, e não a tabela no banco de dados.

Tu pode fazer algo assim:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr class='linha' data-id="1">
    <td>Linha 1</td>
    <td class='coluna'>Não</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha' data-id="2">
    <td>Linha 2</td>
    <td class='coluna'>Não</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha' data-id="3">
    <td>Linha 3</td>
    <td class='coluna'>Não</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='linha' data-id="4">
    <td>Linha 4</td>
    <td class='coluna'>Não</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

O atributo `data-id` contem o `id` referente aquela linha no banco de dados.

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
$(".linha").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .children(".coluna")
    .html("Atualizado: " + $(this).data("id")); 
});
```

A função `$(this).data("id")` acima retorna o `data-id` daquela linha. Você usará isso na sua requisição AJAX.

O `$(this).children(".coluna")` é para obter a coluna específica daquela linha.

*[Veja este exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5BUJ/)*.

Tu pode alterar isto para tudo acontecer ao clique da coluna ou uma imagem dentro dela se quiser. (Use `$(this).parents(".minha-classe")` para obter uma tag pai se necessário).

*[Leia aqui sobre Unobtrusive Javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript)*.